# How do I put viewController's into a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I want to initialize 5 viewController's that I want to be able to flick between in a UIScrollView, when my app loads.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    //standard UIScrollView is added
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*2, 460); //this must be the appropriate size!

    //required to keep your view controllers around
    controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    //just adding two controllers
    LabeledViewController *one = [[LabeledViewController alloc] initWithPosition:0 text:@"one"];

    [scrollView addSubview:one.view];
    [controllers addObject:one];

    LabeledViewController *two = [[LabeledViewController alloc] initWithPosition:1 text:@"two"];
    [scrollView addSubview:two.view];
    [controllers addObject:two];
}
```

**LabeledViewController** is pretty simple, but you can add as much to it as you want:

```
@implementation LabeledViewController

- (id)initWithPosition:(NSInteger)position text:(NSString*)text 
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myPosition = position;
        myText = [text retain];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    //this will setup the position in the UIScrollView
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320*myPosition, 0, 320, 460)];
    self.view = view;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 50)];
    label.text = myText;

    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: Yep, you can always basically use your view controller as a view via its view property. viewController.view or [viewController view].

Comment: Thanks for the code! one note, you should not call [super loadView] in loadView. Instead you can create a view at the beginning UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]init]; add the scrollView to myView and then at the end do self.view = myView

Comment: This works. However I have buttons on my view and i'd like the sub view controller to respond to buttons. I've wired it up properly, but I get error as if my view controller doesn't have the action methods.

Comment: Whatever view controller you want to respond to button taps needs to be passed into `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`