# limiting the view height of uitabbarviewcontroller ios7 without storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5.0.1

I have a tableviewcontroller and on the respective rowclick of the tableviewcontroller i want to show the details of that respective rows detail content.

The row details view will have a fixed content as follows:

1. Header
2. Title below header
3. Image related to title
4. **Here I want to show the respective views of the uitabbarcontroller tab button**

In the above points the content from point 1-3 will cover half of page of viewcontroller which will be fixed & bottom half of the viewcontroller will have the 4th point i.e. views of the respective tabbarbuttons which will change according to the views created for respective tabs.

I am not able to find any solution for keeping the top half of the view fixed. And how to keep the views of the tabbar restricted to the bottom half of the screen.

I am doing this application **without using storyboard** .

Searched a lot but didn't got any solution.

Please provide some example code or tutorial if any.

Following is the image of what i exactly want as i have created same in android.

sorry need to blurr contents of image.

[image]

In the above image following are the things i want fixed:

1. the blue bar at top is header which will stay fixed.
2. the brownbar below the header and the whitish image below the header are also fixed.
3. The four buttons below the image are the tabbar buttons which in IOS will appear at bottom of the screen.
4. below the tabbar button is the view containing the content of the 1st tabbar button.

My question is i want the first 2 of above points be fixed and the viewcontroller containing the views for respective tabbarbuttons should be seen on the rest half of the screen with the 4 tabbar buttons.

So if i click on any of the tab  buttons only its view which is occupied by bottom half of the screen will change & the top half will remain static(fixed).

Hope my explaination make clear some doubts about the question.

----**EDITED SOLUTION** based on what @Simon McLoughlin suggested, following is the code:

I have implemented a function in which i have written code for implementing my scenario.

```
-(void)loadShowDetailsTabBarController
{
    ConceptViewController *conceptViewController;
    CastViewController *castViewController;
    ShowDetailsFeedbackViewController *showDetailsFeedbackViewController;
    PromosViewController *promoViewController;

    UIImage *conceptBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabidle_btn_bg.png"];
    UIImage *conceptBtnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabselected_btn_bg.png"];


    UIImage *castBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabidle_btn_bg.png"];
    UIImage *castBtnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabselected_btn_bg.png"];

    UIImage *feedbackBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabidle_btn_bg.png"];
    UIImage *feedbackBtnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabselected_btn_bg.png"];

    UIImage *promoBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabidle_btn_bg.png"];
    UIImage *promoBtnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showdetailstabselected_btn_bg.png"];

    conceptBtn = [conceptBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    conceptBtnSelected = [conceptBtnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    castBtn = [castBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    castBtnSelected = [castBtnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    feedbackBtn = [feedbackBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    feedbackBtnSelected = [feedbackBtnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    promoBtn = [promoBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    promoBtnSelected = [promoBtnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        conceptViewController = [[ConceptViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConceptViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

        castViewController = [[CastViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CastViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

        showDetailsFeedbackViewController = [[ShowDetailsFeedbackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowDetailsFeedbackViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

        promoViewController = [[PromosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromosViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        conceptViewController = [[ConceptViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConceptViewController" bundle:nil];

        castViewController = [[CastViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CastViewController" bundle:nil];

        showDetailsFeedbackViewController = [[ShowDetailsFeedbackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowDetailsFeedbackViewController" bundle:nil];

        promoViewController = [[PromosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromosViewController" bundle:nil];

    }

    conceptViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CONCEPT" image:conceptBtn selectedImage:conceptBtn];

    castViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CAST" image:castBtn selectedImage:castBtnSelected];

    showDetailsFeedbackViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"FEEDBACK" image:feedbackBtn selectedImage:feedbackBtnSelected];

    promoViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"PROMO" image:promoBtn selectedImage:promoBtnSelected];/**/

    UITabBarController *showDetailstabVC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    showDetailstabVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:conceptViewController,castViewController,showDetailsFeedbackViewController,promoViewController, nil];

    showDetailstabVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 250, screenSize.width, screenSize.height-250);

    self.view.window.rootViewController = showDetailstabVC;

    [self.view addSubview:showDetailstabVC.view];
}
```

Please let me know if my code is correct?

I am able to view what i wanted.

But now the problem is when i click on the tabbar buttons i get the following error:

**exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt)**

The error is not given in debug screen, The app stops at the following line in **main.m** :

**return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));**

Comment: Ok i'm convinced this is either a joke or your a troll. How in the love of god does that picture explain anything ?

Comment: @simon i have blurred the contents of the image and put up explaination below the image for the blurred image which is uploaded.Please read the explaination for image.

Comment: I did and it makes less than no sense

Comment: the top half of the contents of screen i want it fixed and bottom half of the screen should contain the tabbarcontroller and its respective views.

Comment: so then create a UIViewController that has a view on the top and a child UITabbarController on the bottom

Comment: but the views of the uitabbarcontroller will occupy whole of the parent screen area which i want to limit it to bottom half of screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turns out what you are trying to achieve is a `UIViewController` split vertically. Top half being static and bottom half containing a `UITabbarController` that will display `UIViewControllers` that will only occupy the space between the `UITabbar` and the static view.

I thought this could be done with making the `UITabbarController` a child, but I could be wrong. I have had 3 child `UIViewController`'s on a screen before by simply setting the frame. You've said above that that didn't work for you so I see 2 options left.

1. You create all of the tabs content to be smaller. So for example say the top view is 100px in height. In the `UIViewController`'s in the tabs, simply set the frame of the `UITableView` (or the view or whatever the content is) to start at 100px for its `Y` value. This is a fairly bad solution in my opinion however it would require the least effort to do.
2. You create a "Master" `UIViewController` that has a static section at the top and a horizontally scrolling `UIScrollView` with paging enabled. And add the individual `UIViewController`'s as child viewControllers to that. Not sure if you could create a `Tabbar` and listen for events and use that to programmtically scroll it, or if you would have to create your own `UIView` that looks like a `Tabbar` and put buttons on it to scroll left / right.

The second method is a fairly common thing to do. I've worked on a few apps that have done it and have seen many posts online about how to achieve it. Like so: [How do I put viewController's into a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990658/how-do-i-put-viewcontrollers-into-a-uiscrollview) . It Simply requires adding the child viewControllers at increasing `X` values and setting the scrollViews content size to the total. Turn on pagging, turn off vertical scrolling.

Comment: ok will post image of how i want it as i have created same in android and want to create same kind of view in ios

Comment: i tried and was able to set both tabbarcontroller and top section view in one screen but now problem arises is when i click on the tabbar buttons i get the following error:

exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt)

The error is not shown in the debug area but the app stops at the following line in the main.m

This is the line where app stops:

@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: @NiranjanBalkrishnaPrajapati im not near my computer at the minute. Google how to set a break point to catch all exceptions "on throw". There is a menu on the left in the same section as the file explorer that allows you to do this and it will point out the exact error and the line

Comment: that is the line I mentioned in the above comment the app stops at the following line:



autoreleasepool { return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); }

In main.m class

Comment: @NiranjanBalkrishnaPrajapati no thats where the application starts. Every crash happens in the main function of an app. Do what iI said above